# Android AppCompActivity toolbar not showing

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I've been trying to add a custom `toolbar` but it doesn't show.

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="simpleapps.app.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <application
    android:name=".Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_bc_512"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher_bc_512"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

I can't see what is missing, I've followed the principles of the official android tutorial tutorial:
[Setting up a toolbar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up)

Comment: is it invisible or Nothing shows there... is it something like that?

Comment: are you getting an errror'

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Instead of:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/ToolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
/>
```

Use:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ToolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
/>
```

You don't need a theme as it is already applied in the manifest activity tag.

Finally,

Instead of:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Use:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is inside your activity_main.xml

You forgot to add constraints to both your `Toolbar` and the `RelativeLayout` below it.
Update your code with the code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="simpleapps.app.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">
.......
```

> What fixed the problem?

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_toolbar"
```

inside your `RelativeLayout`

The `Toolbar` was there the whole time, it was just covered by your `RelativeLayout`

And just for safe side, add these to your `<Toolbar>`

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Comment: Ok, your phase: "The Toolbar was there the whole time, it was just covered by your RelativeLayout" made me question whether other components were covering the Toolbar and in fact I had a WebView created in the activity but not the layout file that was covering the toolbar! Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't follow your question. Are you asking if your webview is also covering the toolbar?

Comment: It's not a question, its the answer. The webview was covering the toolbar and the relativelayout